# Как отследить окончание звонка, начатого через Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Есть у меня такая функция:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String phoneNumber = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber)).getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как звонок завершён (Окно звонка закрылось и вернулось в моё приложение), выполнилась какая-нибудь моя функция, например `callEnded()`. Как сделать такое?

**P. S.** Возможно лучше делать звонки как-нибудь по-другому? Потому что надо делать много звонков и автоматически...

Comment: Как на счет отслеживать через событие жизненного цикла onResume?

Comment: @MiMEKiZ onResume вызывается два раза - перед звонком и после. И ещё вызывается вообще не при звонке.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартный способ это использование вместо `startActivity()` - `startActivityForResult()`, по окончании Intent'а будет вызван метод `onActivityResult()`, где вы что-то сможете сделать, в частности проверить как был закончен `Intent` и все такое.

[Мануал примерно такой](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html)

Документация [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Comment: Я пытался использовать что-то такое, но там есть проблема, что `onActivityResult` у меня вроде бы два раза вызывался, перед звонком и после...